# The best to way to reinstall DirSync tool

Tags: office-365

Since I have a new tenant in Office 365, I need re-mapping DirSync tool from my old tenant to new one. What is the best way to uninstall and reinstall DirSync tool from the server in order to avoid getting error messages when reinstall DirSync?

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully reinstalled the DirSync tool without problems. Below is the steps I follow:

1. Turn off the Windows Azure Active Directory Sync Service
2. Run SynchronizationService.msi from Windows Azure Active Directory Sync folder
3. Remove Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service
4. Run UnInstallDirectorySync.exe. It will delete all the data file under C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSONLINE\MSSQL\DATA